# I'm getting keyerror and can not import data from csv file

Tags: python

```
def load_data(label_dict):
    x = []
    y = []
    x_keys = ['FEAT_1','FEAT_2','FEAT_3','FEAT_4','FEAT_5','FEAT_6']
    y_keys = ['LABEL'];
    for item in label_dict:
        x.append([float(item[k]) for k in x_keys])
        y.append([float(item[k]) for k in y_keys])

    return (x,y)
```

Error is:

```
File "NID_1.py", line 54, in load_data
    x.append([float(item[k]) for k in x_keys])
KeyError: 'FEAT_1'
```

Comment: What is label_dict?

Comment: Did you use a DictReader to read the csv?

Comment: `for item in label_dict` iterates over what seems like a dictionary. That means it iterates over that dictionary's keys. Since dictionary are mutable, the cannot be keys of dicts and therefore `item['FEAT_1']` cannot work.

Comment: its parameter i have used

Answer (score 0):

`label_dict` seems to be a list of dictionaries that you iterate over.

The error is saying that a dictionary without one of the keys in `x_keys` has been encountered in the scan.

The answer here really depends from what you're passing in as `label_dict`, but if you want to make sure that no error is generated you can ask the dictionary `item` itself which its keys are, without hardcoding them in the `x_keys` list

Python2 :

```
x.append([float(item[k]) for k in item.keys()])
```

Python 3:

```
x.append([float(item[k]) for k in list(item.keys())])
```